# Connect to a new (not the default) Firestore database within a Firebase project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a second database with the id `db-2` (as opposed to `(default)`).

I have all the Firebase config in my code that works to connect to the `(default)` database. I cannot find anywhere the solution to connecting to this new database. I tried

```js
const db = getFirestore(app, "db-2")
```

but I think I misunderstood the use case of the parameters.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `initializeFirestore` and pass a (possibly empty) settings object as the second parameter. So:

```
const db = initializeFirestore(app, {}, "db-2");
```

Comment: When I use this and print `db` I still get the database with id `(default)`.

Comment: That's very unexpected, given that I use precisely this on one of my own, early projects: https://stackblitz.com/edit/dblatency?file=index.js%3AL125